# I got error while using ''image_gallery_saver'' in flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle

this is the error:
''
The android Gradle plugin support only kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':image_gallery_saver' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72

"

BUT my $kotlin_version is 1.6.10

[image: 1]

i tried the plugin with an other app , and it's works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the known issue in this library. For some reason its not working with "android.tools.gradle" version 7.3.1.

You might have to downgrade the version to 7.2.2 or lower.

In your build.gradle replace

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'

with

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'

and try if it's working.

This solution is mentioned in there git repo here https://github.com/hui-z/image_gallery_saver/issues/220